# Node Restart in Shell Script

Tags: node.js, macos, fswatch

I want to rerun the node server, whenever there's changes in file, but i want to use fswatch. i am using fswatch with the shell script like

```
nohup node server.js &
```

but i can't run the same script again since it will throw EADDRINUSE.

- whats the best way to restart the node via script with the help of fswatch (or alternate, without any new installation) ?
- Why node doesn't have something like node restart?

what i could think of is get pid from ps and kill it with script, but i guess there should be a better solution.

Comment: I like forever, https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever. I realize it would probably count as new installation, but still worth looking into, might help others.

Comment: will ``nodemon server,js`` serve your purpose?

Comment: Your might want to look into node-supervisor: https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to do that with the help of fswatch.

```
fswatch -o mydir | xargs -n1 -I{}  ps | grep '[n]ode server.js$' | awk '{system("kill "$1)}'
```

or putting the same code in seperate shell file. and using it as

```
xargs -n1 './location-of-shell-file.sh'
```

when i run grep, that process is also included in ps, so to exclude that i had to use

```
grep '[n]ode server.js'
```

Answer (score -2):

EADDRINUSE comes because of you are already bind on the same port. Node.js has no build-in restart mechanics, so yes, you should use some bash scripts (or frameworks) for good restarting background app